# How to convert fancy/artistic unicode text to ASCII?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, ascii

I have a unicode string like " " and would like to convert it to the ASCII form "thug life".

I know I can achieve this in Python by

```py
import unidecode
print(unidecode.unidecode(' '))
// thug life
```

However, this would asciify also other unicode characters (such as Chinese/Japanese characters, emojis, accented characters, etc.), which I want to preserve.

Is there a way to detect these type of "artistic" unicode characters?

Some more examples:

ｔｈｕｇ ｌｉｆｅ

Thanks for your help!

Comment: cf. [NFC/NFD/NFKD/NFKC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)  [`''..normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import unicodedata
strings = [
  ' ',
  ' ',
  ' ',
  ' ',
  'ｔｈｕｇ ｌｉｆｅ']
for x in strings:
  print(unicodedata.normalize( 'NFKC', x), x)
```

**Output**: `.\62803325.py`

> ```
> thug life  
> thug life  
> thug life  
> thug life  
> thug life ｔｈｕｇ ｌｉｆｅ
> ```

**Resources**:

- `unicodedata` — [Unicode Database](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html)
- [Normalization forms for Unicode text](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)

Comment: Does not work with these cases: "  ", "︎︎︎︎", "ωεłł", "ʜᴀᴋsʜɪ", "", "", "RᗅIPႮ", "ғʀᴇᴇ", "ᕼᗩᑭᑭIᗴᗴ", "υεεɴ".

Comment: @GokulNC You need [Romanization/transliteration of Unicode text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842527/) IMHO… See also https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/

Comment: @GokulNC, did you figure out how to convert such fonts to unicode with python? if yes, please comment you approach here.

Comment: As commented above, `Unidecode` was able to clean most of them, although it did not completely 100% solve the problem.

Comment: yes, same was the case with me. i wanted to know, if you found a way to normalise fonts like "  ", "︎︎︎︎", "ωεłł", "ʜᴀᴋsʜɪ", "", "", "RᗅIPႮ", "ғʀᴇᴇ", "ᕼᗩᑭᑭIᗴᗴ", "υεεɴ" that you had mentioned in your comment.

Comment: I mean, the library mentioned in the answer (`unicodedata`) is different from what I said (`unidecode`). The latter solved the problem. What I meant by "_did not 100% solve_" is that some transliterations were wrong. For example, "ᕼᗩᑭᑭIᗴᗴ" was converted as "hpokikiIgaga". I have now [raised an issue](https://github.com/avian2/unidecode/issues/72) in the package's repo mentioning these cases. Feel free to add more examples there :)

Comment: @GokulNC because `ᕼᗩᑭᑭIᗴᗴ` is `Canadian Syllabics Nunavut H`, `Canadian Syllabics Carrier Po`, `Canadian Syllabics Ki`, `Canadian Syllabics Ki`, `Latin Capital Letter I`, `Canadian Syllabics Carrier Ga`, `Canadian Syllabics Carrier Ga`.

Comment: Yeah you are right. So I am looking for ways to do an appearance-based conversion rather than approximate-phonetic conversion.